# Redundancy analysis triplot interpretation

Tags: interpretation, redundancy-analysis

Redundancy analysis proceeds by multivariate regression of a response matrix Y on explanatory matrix X. The fitted Y values are then submitted to PCA, where the two axes of greatest explanation can be used for plotting the relationship of the axes to both response and explanatory variables.

If these two axes are orthogonal (result of PCA) why then is it said from authoritative sources that e.g. plotted vectors that are at 90 degrees apart are uncorrelated? Should it not be as in the following example:

(0,1), (1,0) are uncorrelated due to orthogonality of axes

(1,1), (-1,1) are correlated (despite 90 degree angle)

Furthermore, I have seen the relative strength of correlation between two vectors be calculated as the dot product. Should the amount of variation explained on each axis be considered? For example with axis 1 variation explained = 25%, axis 2 variation explain = 5%,should it not be that:

(1,0) and (1,1) are much more correlated than (0,1) and (1,1)

Thanks for any clarification.